# How can all the x ticks be forced in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

[image]
After using bokeh to graph a market performance over time, I overwrote the x axis with equally spaced dates. However, I can't seem to force all the dates to appear. Help is appreciated!

Data source:

```
1,2680.4
1.0128,2680.4
1.0256,2680.6
1.0385,2680.9
1.0513,2681.1
1.0641,2681.4
1.0769,2681.6
...
```

Code:

```
import ...

data = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
list_days = []
delta = 60         # timedelta

for i in range(delta + 1):
    d = now + timedelta(days=i)
    list_days.append(d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

p = figure(title='' + now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), plot_width=1200, plot_height=800, x_axis_label = 'Date', y_axis_label='Price')

p.line(data[0].values, data[1].values, line_width=2, alpha=0.5, color='navy')

label_dict = {} 
for i, s in enumerate(list_days): 
    label_dict[i] = s 

p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(
    code=""" var labels = %s; return labels[tick]; """ % label_dict)

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4

show(p)
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your plot. It seems as if you have discrete values at minor ticks and somehow (interpolated?) graphs from minor to minor. You might need to upp the minor datapoints to major ones somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Labels happen on major tick marks, you see the minor tick marks. 
You can switch them off by:

```
yourplot.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None  # x-axis-minor-tick  off 
yourplot.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None  # y-axis-minor-tick  off
```

See [TickLine Doku](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-lines)

If you want to have "more" Dates in between you could set them with a [fixed ticker](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fixedticker), styling what labels to display yourself.